# Access Node image within Page template

Tags: 8, theming

I need to access a Node's image field within the `page.twig.html` template in order to display it in relation to certain page-level elements such as primary/secondary menus and the page title.

In `node.html.twig`, I'm able to access it like so:

```
{{ content.field_responsive_hero_image.0 }}
```

but in `page.html.twig` if I try

```
{{ node.field_responsive_hero_image.0 }}
```

I get the following error:

```
Exception: Object of type Drupal\image\Plugin\Field\FieldType\ImageItem cannot be printed
```

I'm familiar with the workaround of loading the image with

```
<img src="{{file_url(node.field_responsive_hero_image.entity.fileuri)}}" />
```

However, I then lose the title and alt attributes (bad for 508 compliance) as well as the automatic resizing of the image served based on screen size (bad for SEO rankings).

How do I access the Node's image at a page-level?

Comment: If you `{{ dump(node.field_responsive_hero_image.entity | keys) }}`, do you see the title and alt keys? If you can access the `fileuri` you should be able to access the `alt` and `title` values... e.g. `<img src="{{file_url(node.field_responsive_hero_image.entity.fileuri)}}" alt="node.field_responsive_hero_image.entity.alt.value" title="node.field_responsive_hero_image.entity.title.value" />`.

Comment: **Printing node values in page templates is bad bractice!** Simply use a block instead.

Comment: @Prestosaurus that solves most of my problems. The only thing left is serving different images based on the device, but I may be able to work it out with "srcset".

Comment: @leymannx I get that it's bad practice.....just trying to build a page to a design. I'm not sure how using a block would work though....it's still going to be within the same place on the page.

Comment: You'd hide the image from node display and print it via a block instead. Place the block between the menu and page title, export config, done. UI kept intact, templates kept clean, everybody happy.

Comment: You could use Views for that, or build a custom block in a custom module yourself. I'd recommend the latter, as it's a nice exercise to learn something really useful.

Comment: There have been times I've needed to update a theme this way. Most content is in `node`, but the chrome of the site is in `page`. Now, the client wants an image in the header and it isn't worth it to move all the chrome into the node template. I agree that a block is the best approach. When I want an image in the header that's all I want. For every entity in Drupal you add div's. So you would create a custom block type and template, a block instance, export config, etc... Is this more re-usable than just printing the node values in page? Debatable when you consider a real dollar budget.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a preprocess hook (preferred):

```
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_HOOK() for page.html.twig.
 */
function MYTHEME_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  if (isset($variables['node'])) {
    $variables['image'] = $variables['node']->get('field_image')->first()->view('full');
  } 
}
```

Or in Twig:

```
{{ node.field_image.0|view('full') }}
```

To use `|view` install the module https://www.drupal.org/project/twig_tweak